# Observable doesn't execute when used in ngIf

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I am trying to execute an observable chain/pipe depending on a boolean observable that's used in an if condition in a template.

But the code in the pipe() statement never gets executed even though I am using async pipe on the boolean observable in the template.

```
<div>{{isAllowed$ | async}} --- resolves to true or false and shows on html page
<div *ngIf="isAllowed$ | async>
    //other items
</div>

ngOnInit() {
    this.isAllowed$ = callToMethodThatReturnsBooleanObservalble();
  
    this.isAllowed$.pipe(
    tap(val => { // -- never gets executed
        if(val) {
            //make rest call --- never gets executed
        }
    })
)
}
```

It does work if I put subscribe() at the end of the pipe but I thought the async pipe did that for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the pipe to the call you make:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.isAllowed$ = callToMethodThatReturnsBooleanObservalble().pipe(
    tap(val => { 
      if(val) {
           
      }
    })
  );
}
```

The `pipe` method creates a new `Observable`, so when you do it like you had before, that observable is not stored, and also does not get subscribed to in the template

Comment: Triggering a network call from a subscription made in the template to render data doesn't sound like a good idea, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rxjs Subject. This also serves as an observable and can emit data using 'next' whenever you want to update on the change of the data. No need to subscribe manually since you are using "async" pipe.

You can use something like this in your code.

```
    <div>
      <div *ngIf="(isAllowed$ | async)">
        //other items
      </div>
    </div>;
   
   // In your .ts file //
   public isAllowed$ = new Subject<boolean>();

   ngOnInit() {
      // Pass your function that returns a boolean in your subject isAllowed.
      //  and your subscription will trigger whenever there is a change
      this.isAllowed$.next(callToMethodThatReturnsBooleanObservalble());
   }
```